# Configuring Cloudera Connector for MicroStrategy

Tags: odbc, hive, bigdata, cloudera, microstrategy

I have installed **ClouderaHiveODBCSetup_v2_00** on my `windows XP` and I am following instructions as per the following page

https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/con/Cloudera+Connector+for+Tableau

I am get the following error

the setup routine for the cloudera ODBC driver for APACHE hive ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 127

What could be the problem . I have tried with all privileges as an admin

Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean http://go.cloudera.com/microstrategy_connector_download

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera had updated the Hive ODBC driver. Have you try their latest version of the driver? The latest version runs fine on XP.

Here is the download link: 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products/downloads-listing/connectors/cloudera-odbc-drivers.html